# How to change an interorgative sentence from active to passive

Tags: passive-voice, interrogatives

> Are you going to sell the book?

I change it as follows :

> Is the book going to be sold

My friends said it's not the correct answer 
Please help

Answer (score 1):

Your passive reconstruction works grammatically but you are leaving out the extra information "you" from the first sentence.

You could just add this to the end:

> Is the book going to be sold by you?

But you can also clean the sentence up a bit this way:

> Will the book be sold by you?